# Resetting counters for every new chapter

Tags: chapters, counters

I would like to reset the counters for everything, figures, tables, algorithms, lemmas, definitions, equations and others. So that they start at one again, for every chapter.
Is it possible or do I have to do it separately for each?

PS: I use `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This should be default if you are using e.g. the `book` class. If you are using something else or have defined counters on your own, plase provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: in most classes that is the default

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{book}

Comment: So I cannot do it for all classes at once?

Comment: different classes have different requirements, especially those classes provided by publishers.  so no, it is not possible to reset all counters for all classes at once, nor would it be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to do it for each. The numbering system is based on counters, and each number has its own counter. Resetting all counters would include things you don't want to reset, like page numbers. As said in the comments, different document classes treat the counters different. In `book` for example, things like `section`, `subsection`, `equation`, `table` and `figure` are automatically reset at each chapters start. But for example `theorem` and `lemma`, and other things you define by your self, you need define it such that it the counter reset at chapter start. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] %%% Reset theorem counter at chapter start
\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{theorem}
  As can be see in Figure~\ref{fig:Test1}...
\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Test figure.}
  \label{fig:Test1}
\end{figure}

\section{Second section}
\begin{theorem}
  Test
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{theorem}
  Euler's identity
  \begin{equation}
    e^{i\pi}+1=0
  \end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Test figure.}
  \label{fig:Test2}
\end{figure}

\section{Second section}
\begin{theorem}
  Test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

First chapter:
[image]

Second chapter:
[image]